# Unity3d 1st person camera and lookAt target

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, transform

I'm making a game with firstperson camera. Now I want the player to look at items during cutscenes. This works. the only problem is when the cutscene is over the camera shoots back to the old position so it looks weird. I tried locking and unlocking the cursor so it's in the center but this does nothing. Any ideas?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using Cursor = UnityEngine.Cursor;

public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour
{
public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
public Transform playerBody;
public bool mayLook;
private bool _lookAtTarget;

private float xRotation = 0;

private Transform _target;
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    mayLook = true;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (mayLook)
    {
        HandleLook();
    }
    
    if (_lookAtTarget)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(_target.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, 5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

void HandleLook()
{
    if (mayLook)
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}

public void lookTowards(Transform target)
{
    _target = target;
    _lookAtTarget = true;
}

public void resetCamera()
{
    _lookAtTarget = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
    mayLook = true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save the camera's rotation before the cutscene starts and then restore it after the cutscene is over. Add a Quaternion variable to store the camera's rotation, then use it to set the camera's rotation in your resetCamera method.

It could go like so:

```
public class PlayerLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ...

    private Quaternion savedRotation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        mayLook = true;
        // Save the initial camera rotation
        savedRotation = transform.rotation;
    }

    // ...

    public void lookTowards(Transform target)
    {
        _target = target;
        _lookAtTarget = true;
    }

    public void resetCamera()
    {
        _lookAtTarget = false;
        // Restore the saved camera rotation
        transform.rotation = savedRotation;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        mayLook = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want to return to the old position but it does it anyways :(

Comment: Oh it seems i missunderstood the question. So what if you did the same but instead of it happening before the cutscene starts, it happens right after its complete?

Comment: I walk into a building. I use my script to lookat a person sitting there and put maylook to false so I cant look away. when I put maylook to true again my camera shoots back to look at the place i was looking before the cutscene

Comment: Well since you change the "look" rotation and position it shouldn't snap back.. So if you don't want the camera to snap back why do you use a resetCamera() method?

Comment: The reset method was a test. even without it the camera snaps back :(